Close child window when refreshed
How do you close a child window, a window opened from window.open, when the child window is refreshed or navigates elsewhere?
I have tried the code below but it doesn't work:
const popout = window.open('', '', 'popout');
popout.onbeforeunload = () => {
    popout.close();
};

Similar code works to close the child window when the parent is refreshed:
const popout = window.open('', '', 'popout');
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    popout.close();
};

I have seen other sites do this but I can't figure it out, instead left with a blank popped out window that has to be manually closed.

Try popout.onunload

Is the document in the popout in the same domain? If it's in a different domain you may not be able to access anything in it from your original script.

I tried popout.onunload but it is the same result. Both event handlers are firing as I can see them printing console logs, the close() part just doesn't do anything.
I'm not sure if it counts as the same domain, I'm opening it just like in the code I posted. The original script can close it when a button is clicked in the pop out or within the parent UI.

@Barmar turns out popout.onunload does work if I just try it in the dev console the same as above. I must have some other context issue preventing it working in my app. Thanks.

So you're just opening a blank page and waiting for the user to navigate away from it?

It renders part of the UI in the pop out whilst maintaining normal UI functionality in the main window. Refreshing, closing or using a button within the pop that I've rendered will return the UI to the main window. It works now though, it was 1am and I was using addEventListener('onunload') without realizing. addEventListener('unload') works. Thanks again.

I think your window.open statement is wrong.
You see, there's no url provided in the first parameter and the third parameter is the new window features... And 'popout' is not a valid value for the third parameter.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#windowfeatures
PS: This snippet will never work because it blocks popups (new windows)... Just copy the code, open new tab and enter about:blank then paste the code at the console. It will open a popup, then you can return to the about:blank page (without closing the popup) and click the generated link. When the page unloads the popup will close.


let myPopupWindow;

const myAnchorLabel = 'Try clicking here.';
const myAnchorLink  = 'about:blank';

const newAnchor = document.createElement('a');
{
  newAnchor.href = myAnchorLink;
  newAnchor.textContent = myAnchorLabel;
}

try
{
  myPopupWindow = window.open('about:blank', 'popup', 'popup; width=300; height=300;');
  
  myPopupWindow.document.body.appendChild(newAnchor);
  
  const myInterval = setInterval
  (
    () =>
    {
      if ( ! myPopupWindow.closed )
      {
        myPopupWindow?.history?.length && myPopupWindow?.close();
         
        myPopupWindow.closed && console.log('myPopupWindow.closed:', myPopupWindow.closed);
      }
    },
    100
  );
  
  console.log('myPopupWindow:');
  console.log(myPopupWindow);
}
catch ( Issue )
{
  console.log('Error while opening a new window:', Issue?.message ?? Issue);
}




Your code doesn't close the page when you refresh the child window which was the question. I've fixed it now though thanks to comments above.

@spaceman I misunderstood the question. I just adjusted the snippet. It's working like intended. See if it will resolve the issue.
